# Changing the order of integration for $\int_{-t}^t \int_{z-a}^z \int_z^{y+a} f(x,y,z) d x d y d z$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I'd like to change the order of integration in the following triple integral
\begin{equation*}
\int_{-t}^t \int_{z-a}^z \int_z^{y+a} f(x,y,z) d x d y d z
\end{equation*}
where $a  > 0$ and $t > 0$. I'd like to integrate over $z$ first. The region of integration appears to be a prism; however, I'm having a hard time getting the correct limits.

Comment: Have you tried drawing it out carefully on graph paper?

Comment: what is the relation between $a$ and $t$ ? ( $ a\ge t$ or $a\le t$)

Comment: I suppose if I had to choose, I would take $t \leq a$.

Answer (score 0):

Not a terribly good idea but you can do "blindly" via the inequalities
$$z\le x\le y+a,$$
$$z-a\le y\le z,$$
$$-t\le z\le t.$$
The $z$ limits are obvious:
$$y\le z\le x.$$
The upper limit for $x$ is also obviously $x\le y.$
Now, using $-t\le z$ and $z\le x$:
$$-t\le x\le y.$$
Finally,
$$-(t + a)\le y\le t.$$

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I was also attempting to do so along these lines, but wasn't positive my limits were correct. For example, I think the limits for $z$ should actually be $\max \left\{y,-t \right\} \leq z \leq x$. I also think you flipped the relation for $x,y$, I think it should be $y \leq x$. I believe the limits for $x$ should be something like $\max\left\{-t,y\right\} \leq x \leq t$.

Comment: This is what I believed the limits should be: $\int_{-t-a}^t \int_{\max \left\{ -t, y \right\} }^{y+a} \int_{\max \left\{-t,y \right\}}^{\min \left\{ x,t \right\}} dz dx dy$. I'd really like it if someone could confirm it though.

Comment: @John, both wrong. Do the calculations with $f = 1$. I will re-check the answer.